# Regression analysis: What's the best practice to code death in a balanced panel data set?

Tags: panel-data

Let's say I have a sample of 3 and I want to estimate the effect of a number of external factors on their chance of survival. That is, I want to estimate what can cause death.

```
| ID | AGE | SEX    | DAY | ALIVE |
|----|-----|--------|-----|-------|
| 1  | 50  | MALE   | 1   | TRUE  |
| 1  | 50  | MALE   | 2   | FALSE |
| 1  | 50  | MALE   | 3   | FALSE |
| 2  | 65  | FEMALE | 1   | TRUE  |
| 2  | 65  | FEMALE | 2   | FALSE |
| 2  | 65  | FEMALE | 3   | FALSE |
| 3  | 70  | FEMALE | 1   | TRUE  |
| 3  | 70  | FEMALE | 2   | TRUE  |
| 3  | 70  | FEMALE | 3   | TRUE  |
```

Both individual 1 and 2 die on day 2. So the effect I want to measure as causing their death is in fact limited to day 2. Yet, excluding divine intervention, on day 3 they will still be dead - but a regression model based on balanced panel data will still estimate coefficients predicting their dead also on day 3. What would be the most convincing approach? To differentiate their status maintaining a binary coding for the dependent variable `ALIVE`?

Answer (score 0):

This is basically survival analysis, and it's an entire subfield of statistics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis

You probably want to find a textbook or introductory course for this, since there is too much to explain here. But essentially you are trying to model the expected time until the person dies. In other words, your first person would have a dependent variable value of Y1 = 2 since they died on day 2. The second person would also have a value of Y2 = 2. Person 3 is more complicated since they dont die during the sample period, which is an example of censored data which is (again) something integral to the field of survival analysis.